# Wpf custom LineArrow shape rotation

Tags: wpf, rotation, shapes

The following code allows me to draw a line with arrows:

```
public sealed class LineArrow : Shape
{
    #region X1
    public double X1
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue( X1Property ); }
        set { SetValue( X1Property, value ); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for X1.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty X1Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "X1", typeof( double ), typeof( LineArrow ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( 0.0,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure ) ); 
    #endregion

    #region Y1
    public double Y1
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue( Y1Property ); }
        set { SetValue( Y1Property, value ); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Y1.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Y1Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "Y1", typeof( double ), typeof( LineArrow ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( 
            0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure ) );
    #endregion

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            var lineStart = new Point( X1, Y1 );
            var lineEnd = new Point( this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight );
            var lineAngle = Math.Atan2( this.ActualHeight, this.ActualWidth );

            RotateTransform rotation = new RotateTransform() { Angle = lineAngle * 180 / Math.PI, CenterX = 0.5, CenterY = 0.5 };
            TranslateTransform translate = new TranslateTransform( lineEnd.X, lineEnd.Y );

            StreamGeometry streamGeometry = new StreamGeometry();
            using( StreamGeometryContext geometryContext = streamGeometry.Open() )
            {
                geometryContext.BeginFigure( lineStart, true, true );
                geometryContext.LineTo( lineEnd, true, true );

                //left arrow
                geometryContext.BeginFigure( lineStart, true, true );
                geometryContext.PolyLineTo( new List<Point>()
                {
                     rotation.Transform( new Point( 0, -15 ) ),
                     rotation.Transform( new Point( -15, 0 ) ),
                     rotation.Transform( new Point( 0, 15 ) )
                }, true, true );

                //right arrow
                geometryContext.BeginFigure( lineEnd, true, true );
                geometryContext.PolyLineTo( new List<Point>()
                {
                    translate.Transform( rotation.Transform( new Point( 0, -15 ) ) ),
                    translate.Transform( rotation.Transform( new Point( 15,0 ) ) ),
                    translate.Transform( rotation.Transform( new Point( 0, 15 ) ))
                }, true, true );
            }

            streamGeometry.Freeze();
            return streamGeometry;              
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how it behaves:

[image]

How can I make the arrows preserve their initial size of 15x15 while rotating and in particular while approaching an angle of 180 or 90 degrees?

Answer (score 2):

Let's think about the geometrical background. You have a center and you have an arrow. The length of the arrow should not change when the angle changes. What is the shape we have just described? Yes, you are right, it is a **circle**. Now, what are the properties of the circle? Its **center** is the point **(X1, Y1)** you are using as the stable point and its **radius** is the initial length of the arrow. Essentially, you intend to find the end point based on center, radius and angle.

Let's suppose the angle is alpha. In that case, the **(X2, Y2)** coordinate you are searching for is:

> X2 = X1 + radius * cos(alpha)
>
> Y2 = Y1 + radius * sin(alpha)

Comment: Shouldn't RotateTransform take care of that math applying sin to y and cos to x?

Comment: @sam, I am not an expert of wpf, but I happen to know how the formula of the desired coordinates. As an outsider of wpf, the most I can do is to explain the theoretical background. That way I am sure you will be able to write the correct code in the style (with or without RotateTransform) you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You should define `X1`, `Y1`, `X2` and `Y2` properties like `Line` does.

Then the drawing could be done like shown below, probably replacing the constants for the arrow dimensions with the value of another dependency property. It first draws a horizontal line with arrows with the length of the vector that connects the start and end point, and then rotates it appropriately.

```
protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
{
    get
    {
        var vector = new Point(X2, Y2) - new Point(X1, Y1);
        var angle = Vector.AngleBetween(new Vector(1, 0), vector);
        var geometry = new StreamGeometry();

        using (var sgc = geometry.Open())
        {
            // left arrow
            sgc.BeginFigure(new Point(X1, Y1), true, true);
            sgc.LineTo(new Point(X1 + 15, Y1 - 10), true, true);
            sgc.LineTo(new Point(X1 + 15, Y1 + 10), true, true);

            // right arrow
            sgc.BeginFigure(new Point(X1 + vector.Length, Y1), true, true);
            sgc.LineTo(new Point(X1 + vector.Length - 15, Y1 - 10), true, true);
            sgc.LineTo(new Point(X1 + vector.Length - 15, Y1 + 10), true, true);

            // line
            sgc.BeginFigure(new Point(X1 + 15, Y1), false, false);
            sgc.LineTo(new Point(X1 + vector.Length - 15, Y1), true, true);
        }

        geometry.Transform = new RotateTransform(angle, X1, Y1);
        geometry.Freeze();

        return geometry;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code solves a part of the problem. Basically it handles the rotation the right way and i thank you for that but if you try to make that shape fill a parent container the arrows grows accordingly. In my particular case I am binding like this shape width and height to parent width and height. Any idea?

Comment: Then I'm not sure why you have the X1 and Y1 properties at all. Instead of drawing from `(X1, Y1)` to `(X2, Y2)` you could simply draw from `(0, 0)` to `(ActualWidth, ActualHeight)`. Just replace that in my code sample.

Comment: But if I do we are back to square one cause arrows shrink. I actually did that in my question code!

Comment: No, just replace X1 and Y1 by 0, X2 by ActualWidth and Y2 by ActualHeight.

Comment: A cleaner solution might be to stick with the X1, Y1, X2 and Y2 properties, and in your use case bind X2 and Y2 like `X2="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=parentOfTheLineArrow}"`

Comment: I tried the replacements but trust me the behavior is the same we can see in the question. I can't bind directly to x2 cause i use a ContentPresenter to show various shapes and X2,Y2 properties are specific to some shapes only. Maybe i should override measureOverride to take care of the fixed size of the arrows so they don't shrink? I appreciate your help.